# OSMNX edges (u,v), (v,u) with same attributes

Tags: python, graph, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am solving ATSP's and Mixed Rural Postman Problems (visit a subset of edges and arcs of the graph) on graphs froms OSMNX.

However I wondered something: namely the oneway attribute of an edge could be true or false, I thought meaning this would be an edge or an arc. However i found that some edges (u,v) is an exact copy of (v,u) if oneway is false. Meaning that it are arcs.

See an example edge below:
u                                                    29643182
v                                                    29642967
key                                                         0
osmid                                                 4666441
oneway                                                  False
lanes                                                     NaN
ref                                                       NaN
highway                                           residential
maxspeed                                                   30
reversed                                                 True
length                                                101.755
geometry    LINESTRING (6.5082881 52.9963783, 6.5079751 52...
bridge                                                    NaN
name                                              Zeeltstraat
junction                                                  NaN
access                                                    NaN
area                                                      NaN

u                                                    29642967
v                                                    29643182
key                                                         0
osmid                                                 4666441
oneway                                                  False
lanes                                                     NaN
ref                                                       NaN
highway                                           residential
maxspeed                                                   30
reversed                                                False
length                                                101.755
geometry    LINESTRING (6.5079751 52.9972738, 6.5082881 52...
bridge                                                    NaN
name                                              Zeeltstraat
junction                                                  NaN
access                                                    NaN
area                                                      NaN

In short: is osmnx a directed or mixed graph? So if (u,v) has oneway False and is thus an edge can it be traversed both ways when for example calculating shortest path? Or has it two arcs connecting u and v (u,v) and (v,u)?

Because a problem arises then when I add nodes or delivery adres to the graph: if the adress (i) is on edge (u,v) i split the edge (u,v) in (u,i) and (i,v). Does this mean to get to i it has to travel from u?

Comment: Please ensure to provide a fully reproducible example (as a minimal code)

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> In short: is osmnx a directed or mixed graph?

The OSMnx [documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/) answers your question (emphasis added):

> Using OSMnx’s graph module, you can retrieve any spatial network data (such as streets, paths, canals, etc) from the Overpass API and model them as NetworkX MultiDiGraphs. OSMnx automatically processes network topology from the original raw OpenStreetMap data such that nodes represent intersections/dead-ends and edges represent the street segments that link them. MultiDiGraphs are nonplanar directed graphs with possible self-loops and parallel edges. Thus, a one-way street will be represented with a single directed edge from node u to node v, but **a bidirectional street will be represented with two reciprocal directed edges (with identical geometries): one from node u to node v and another from v to u, to represent both possible directions of flow.** OSMnx can convert a MultiDiGraph to a MultiGraph if you prefer an undirected representation of the network.

For more on that, you can refer to the NetworkX MultiDiGraph [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html). You also asked:

> So if (u,v) has oneway False and is thus an edge can it be traversed both ways when for example calculating shortest path?

No. The oneway=False attribute is simply an [OpenStreetMap way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/4666441) attribute being copied down to the graph edge. See the bolded text in the OSMnx documentation quote above.

> if the adress (i) is on edge (u,v) i split the edge (u,v) in (u,i) and (i,v). Does this mean to get to i it has to travel from u?

Yes, unless you also split edge (v,u) into (v,i) and (i,u) as well.